# Is there a way to find a dll reference in Visual Studio?

Tags: clickonce, smo

I have a ClickOnce-deployed project. Last release, I found ClickOnce added a `Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.Starace.dll` as prerequiste. I'm not sure why it was added.

It seems if I pen the project on a pc that doesn't have this file in the GAC, the ClickOnce will not add this file as prerequesite. I searched the namespace and couldn't figure out where I reference this dll.

My question is : is there a way or tool that can help me where this dll is referenced?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check the dependencies of your assemblies.

Comment: Thanks eoghank, it helpes. and also I find out that one of my pc has vs 2010 installed and vs.2010 installed a newer version of smo in the gac. the newer smo dlls depend on Microsoft.SqlServer.Diagnostics.Starace.dll. Another machine only has vs.2008 installed, doesn't has this problem. Thanks again!